# C# unexpected behavior while adding/removing Combobox items while the list is dropped down

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to be able to properly update the Combobox list items while the list is shown.

I'm populating a Combobox in DropDownList mode with all the available serial ports.  I subscribed to the "Device Changed" event and updating this ComboBox in the event handler.  If the currently selected port is no longer available (ie, user unplugged the USB Serial Port), then I want the current selection to show a blank string by doing combobox1.Text = "" or combox1.SelectedIndex = -1.  This works pretty good for the most part except for if an update comes in while the user has click on the Combobox and the list is showing.

For example, if the current list contains "Com1", "Com2" and SelectedIndex is set to -1 (thus current selection shows blank) and the user clicks on the Combobox to open the list and does not move the mouse down to select anything.  Then before the user clicks again to close the list, he/she unplugs Com1.  Now an update is triggered and I can see the list updating live to now only shows "Com2" and the current selected text shows blank.

However, when the user clicks on the Combobox again (without select anything from the list) to close the list, .Net will select Com2 (which is the first item on the list) instead of leaving the SelectedIndex at -1 and the current selection at blank.  I don't understand what's going on there.  What's more strange is that it seems to leave the current selected text at blank the very first time and only selects the first item by default after the 1st or 2nd time after launching my application.

If I config the control to DropDown mode, then it does leave the current selection at blank after the user closes the list, but the SelectedIndex is set to 0.  Although this seem like some kind of bug (or feature) in .net, I'm kinda ok with this solution, but can anyone tell me if what I'm doing is ok and it will work like this in the future?  Is there any documentation on how to properly update the combobox list while the list is shown?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, but I'd say the 'proper' way would be to first close the dropdown and then update and then re-open.. Actually I wouldn't be surprised if the control crashed when you mess with the Items while they are displayed..

Comment: I'm updating the list in the GUI thread (by using control.Invoke).  That should be ok no?  It hasn't crashed yet.  Closing and then re-opening (is that possible?) sounds like a bad thing for the user to experience.

Comment: Thanks TaW.  It worked great.  Just set DroppedDown to false and then true afterwards.  That IS the proper way right?

Comment: Imo it is. Wrt to user experience: Unless you do it all the time, I think it is preferrable to changing the data while the user is looking at it..